# Passing array of objects between views using the same tab bar controller, Swift 3

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Following the tutorial to pass data between views using the same tab bar controller: (add "https//:" in front, need 10 reputation to post 2 links) makeapppie.com/2015/02/04/swift-swift-tutorials-passing-data-in-tab-bar-controllers/

It works perfectly when I am only passing a single object, but not when I am trying to pass an array of the same object.

I've created a simple app to illustrate my problem clearer.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4APn.png

The object

```
class Item: NSObject {
```

}

The custom tab bar controller

```
class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {

var addedItemArray = [Item]()

var addedItem = Item()
```

}

The first view controller

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

var addedItem = Item()
var addedItemArray = [Item]()
@IBOutlet var ItemLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let tbc = tabBarController as! CustomTabBarController
    addedItem = tbc.addedItem
    addedItemArray = tbc.addedItemArray
    //creates the first item in the array
    addedItemArray.append(Item())
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print("addedItem:\(addedItem)")
    print("addedItemArray:\(addedItemArray)")
}

@IBAction func addItem() {
    //adds additional item to addedItemArray
    addedItemArray.append(Item())
    print(addedItemArray)
}
```

}

The second view controller

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

var addedItem = Item()
var addedItemArray = [Item]()
@IBOutlet var ItemLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let tbc = tabBarController as! CustomTabBarController
    addedItem = tbc.addedItem
    addedItemArray = tbc.addedItemArray
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print("addedItem:\(addedItem)")
    print("addedItemArray:\(addedItemArray)")
}
```

}

When I run the code, I get the following in the console, which is the intended output:

```
addedItem:<Tab_bar_test.Item: 0x60000001d020>
addedItemArray:[<Tab_bar_test.Item: 0x60800001ce20>]
```

However, when I click on the second tab, I get this:

```
addedItem:<Tab_bar_test.Item: 0x60000001d020>
addedItemArray:[]
```

So for some reason, **the program passes a single object, but not the array of object.**

I'd like to know why, and how to fix this using best practices of Swift 3. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think a problem is that Array is value type. So when you pass it in **viewDidLoad** in both controllers you created copy of this Arrays. Then when you add item in your first view controller this change don't have affect on the array in Second controller and TabBarController. You need to use **NSMutableArray** for this but it's bad way.

Comment: Hey Sergey, thanks for the reply. What would be a good way to achieve this then? Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: You can create class where you will store all shared data. Class is the reference type, so when you will change class in one view controller you will have same changes in second.

Comment: Thanks again. I got it working by creating a new class to store the arrays. Not sure if I did it in a way you were talking about though. My next question would be: is this the best practice in achieving what I want?

Comment: I talked about this. Can you explains what you try to do?

Comment: Created a new class called Storage with type NSObject. Added var storedItem = [Item]() to it. Then I created an instance of Storage in the custom tab controller called storage. Accessed it in the the views like this tbc.storage.storedItem.

Comment: Sounds normal. Just one thought. You did not need to inherit the class from NSObject.

Comment: I tried to make Storage with type NSArray, and NSMutableArray. But got errors saying Storage has no member append when "tbc.storage.append(Item())" is executed in the views. How would you approach this? Or am I just doing it wrong?

Comment: Also, is the answer below a good approach in achieving this? How does it compare with my current approach (subclassing tab bar controller)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use a shared array using singleton or a static class

ex:

```
class Global : NSObject {
static let sharedInstance = Global()
var addedItemArray = [Item]()
}
```

you can call it in any view you want

first view

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
var addedItem = Item()
var addedItemArray = [Item]()
@IBOutlet var ItemLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
let tbc = tabBarController as! CustomTabBarController
addedItem = tbc.addedItem
addedItemArray = Global.addedItemArray
//creates the first item in the array
Global.addedItemArray.append(Item())
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
print("addedItemArray:\(Global.addedItemArray)")
}

@IBAction func addItem() {
//adds additional item to addedItemArray
Global.addedItemArray.append(Item())
print(Global.addedItemArray)
}
```

to call the array from any view just call it like this Global.addedItemArray

Comment: Hi Ali Hassoun, thanks for the reply. This worked after I changed Global.addedItemArray to Global.sharedInstance.addedItemArray. Is creating a global variable like this a good practice? I recall reading somewhere where people add something to the app delegate to access it globally and this was claimed to be a bad practice. I'm not sure if this is the same thing.

Comment: oh sorry i forget to add ,sharedInstance ,it's not a bad practice if you manage the access to this variabels

Comment: Great to know. Could you give me an example of how to manage the access to a global variable? I'm fairly new to all this. Thanks again.

Comment: use semaphore for example 
    
String test // this variable is shared between all classes
bool variable_x_is_busy  = false

//class x want to use the variable test
so in class x
if(variable_x_is_busy==false){
variable_x_is_busy = true;
//do what ever you want 
variable_x_is_busy = false;
}
for class y the same
or you can use notification center to notify the class when the variable become free to use